# Why are Batch exit codes mangled when returned to PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, exit-code

Running this code inside of powershell gives strange results:

```
PS> .\test.bat; $lastexitcode
>exit /b 0
2

PS> cmd /c exit /b 0; $lastexitcode
0
```

Can someone explain how to correct the batch file version? I also want to point out that exit values other than `0` work correctly.

Comment: what does the batch file do?

Comment: 2nd line it is echoed 'exit /b 0'

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce using `exit /b <code>` in PSv2, it appears to work as expected in PSv3. For PSv2 it started work as expected when I removed the `/b` which means `When used in a batch script, this option will exit only the script (or subroutine) but not CMD.EXE`.

There are a number issues reported around PowerShell handling exit codes incorrectly:
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=exit%2520code

I didn't see this in particular, but that's not to say it wasn't fixed in PSv3.

Answer (score 0):

All these solutions work. If someone can explain I would appreciate it:

```
PS> & cmd.exe /c 'test.bat && exit'; $lastexitcode
>exit /b 0
0

PS> cmd.exe /c 'test.bat && exit'; $lastexitcode
>exit /b 0
0
```